# Is there a character repetition operator or function in R?

Tags: r

Is there a simple way to do this in R?

`paste0( rep(" ", times=i), collapse="" )`

This would be equivalent to Perl's x operator:

`" " x $i`

I'm hoping for something in the default packages.  I would rather not load a package just to do this.

Comment: I think it's fair to duplicate with that question, but this one should not be deleted as it is expressed a bit differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `strrep`

```
i <- 10
strrep(" ", i)
#[1] "          "
```

Comment: Thanks.  I knew that once.  `strrep` should be in the "See Also" section on the `rep` help page.